# How to Split a column value which has $$ in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

It might be a silly question but I am new to hive and trying few things.

Problem is, I have a column in a table which has values with **$$** in it like ABC12$$FRG3
, I am exporting it to different hive table, So i need only first part of the value like **ABC12** in the given case, I tried below approach

```
Select regexp_extract(id,'^(\\w.*)\\$${2}(\\w.*)$',1) as app from tempTable;
```

I also tried Split function in hive

```
select split(collection_id,'\\$$') as app from tempTable;
```

Both are not working, Its giving the full string (original) without split Am i missing something in it ?

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? A syntax error? Runtime error? Unexpected results (what do they look like and what you expect)?

Comment: An Unexpected result its coming like **ABC12$$FRG3** but i need it like  **ABC12** after split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's due to the fact that you have doubled the `$` symbol in your regex.
You should try

```
Select regexp_extract(id,'^(\\w.*)\\${2}(\\w.*)$',1) as app from tempTable;
```

Comment: Ya it worked $$ was the culprit, Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the $$ in the expression ***'^(\w.*)\$${2}(\w.*)$*'** Remove one $ symbol from the expression. The below will resolve the problem.

```
Select regexp_extract(id,'^(\\w.*)\\${2}(\\w.*)$',1) as app from tempTable;
```